# ONNX GRAPH PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, onnx

python loading onnx model as a protocol buffer,

one of the objects you getting while loading onnx model is a GRAPH,
GRAPH containing -"nodes", "initializer" ,"attribute" etc,

my question is - does "nodes", "initializer", "attribute" have any order with logic connection to neural network execution  ? or it's ordering randomly?

TIA

yeuo

Comment: the node are order topologically (you will not get node before visiting at its predecessors). initializers are just constants - the order doesn't matter. so are the attributes...

Answer (score 0):

The "Intializer" and "Attribute" are referred by names, they are order independent. The Nodes are linked by a list of named inputs and named outputs, inputs and outputs are positionally associated with operator inputs and outputs.

- An input of node must refer to either a graph Input or a graph Initializer or a node Output.
- An output of node either introduces a value in the graph or refers to a graph Output.

Anyway, "nodes", "initializer", and "attribute" are always referred by names. For details, see [ONNX IR](https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/docs/IR.md)